# error "fork/exec /var/task/main: no such file or directory" while executing aws-lambda function

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, handler

Getting `error fork/exec /var/task/main: no such file or directory` while executing lambda function.

I am using windows platform to run and build code in Go.

I have done following steps to deploy go aws-lambda handler:

1. Written code in go language with VSCode in windows platform
2. Build project with : go build main.go
3. Convert main.exe to main.zip
4. Uploaded main.zip with handler name main aws-lambda fuction using aws console account
5. Created test event to test lambda function
6. Got error "fork/exec /var/task/main: no such file or directory while executing lambda function"

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

// Request represents the requested object
type Request struct {
    ID    int    `json:"ID"`
    Value string `json:"Value"`
}

// Response represents the Response object
type Response struct {
    Message string `json:"Message"`
    Ok      bool   `json:"Ok"`
}

// Handler represents the Handler of lambda
func Handler(request Request) (Response, error) {
    return Response{
        Message: fmt.Sprint("Process Request Id %f", request.ID),
        Ok:      true,
    }, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

build command

```
go build main.go
```

Detail Error in AWS console

```
{
  "errorMessage": "fork/exec /var/task/main: no such file or directory",
  "errorType": "PathError"
}
```

Log Output in AWS console

```
START RequestId: 9ef206ed-5538-407a-acf0-06673bacf2d7 Version: $LATEST
fork/exec /var/task/main: no such file or directory: PathError
null
END RequestId: 9ef206ed-5538-407a-acf0-06673bacf2d7
REPORT RequestId: 9ef206ed-5538-407a-acf0-06673bacf2d7  Duration: 0.64 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 31 MB  Init Duration: 1.49 ms
```

Comment: Change handler from code runtime setting to appropriate handler name

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Run following commands in command prompt

```
set GOOS=linux
set GOARCH=amd64
set CGO_ENABLED=0
```

After this , build your project and upload zip file to aws console lambda

like this

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o main main.go`

Reference Link : https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go

Comment: While it wasn't a problem in this example, I think it might be worth pointing out that the executable has to be called "main", not just the function in the code.  I found this out the hard way when following the instructions above.

Comment: Yes you are right, that the executable has to be called "main", not just the function in the code.

Comment: After the first step I only had to do 'go build -o main main.go', zipped the main file that appeared and uploaded to AWS. That solved my issue at least

Comment: Yes the executable name is key - but the name doesn't strictly need to be `main`. One can change the `Handler` name on the AWS side to another executable name.

Comment: When using the `provided.al2` runtime, the handler executable should be named `bootstrap`

Answer (score 45):

In my case the problem was default setted handler to '**hello**' function.

Needed to change it to '**main**' via AWS Lambda view panel -> Basic Settings -> Edit.

[image: AWS Lambda function]

Comment: this can now be found under "Runtime Settings"

Comment: why in the F is the default handler set to "hello" on a new Lambda function? Even the basic tutorial has you name everything "main"!

Answer (score 12):

There are two reasons can happen:

1. You did't use **GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64** with go build, so try:

   GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main main.go
2. You used to build this programm some CI function with golang-alpine base image, so try to use full golang image instead.

Comment: using the standard serverless framework boiler code, this solves the error

Answer (score 10):

Recently I was facing similar issue, and I solved it. As the error says it s finding executable with handle name, so you should name your executable same as handler.

Follow these steps and your will not get this error, I am using PowerShell

```
> go.exe get -u github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cmd/build-lambda-zip # If you do not this have utility earlier
> $env:GOOS = "linux"
> $env:GOARCH = "amd64"
> $env:CGO_ENABLED = "0"
> go build -o .\Handler .\main.go # considering your are in the same directory where your main.go or handler code is present
> ~\Go\Bin\build-lambda-zip.exe -o .\Handler.zip .\Handler
```

Upload this code, and change handler name to Handler(name of the executable that you created above)
[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Naming the Handler in AWS lambda function 'Handler' is a important step, once the steps mentioned above have been followed.

Answer (score 3):

In my embarrasing case I was zipping the folder from outside so the path in the zip I was uploading was 'folder/main'

Comment: I was doing this exact thing... it happens to the best of us lol.  Also, good idea to make sure all names match up as well o.O

Answer (score 3):

You can find the description when you click `AWS Lambda` > `Functions` > `<Your function name>` > `Handler info`
[image]

> You can tell the Lambda runtime which handler method to invoke by
> setting the handler parameter on your function's configuration.
>
> When you configure a function in Go, the value of the handler setting
> is the executable file name. For example, using Handler would call the
> function in the package main of the Handler executable file.

It means that your file which has a handler function is not necessarily named `main.go`. My Handler on AWS is `hello` and I use this command to create executable file `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o hello hello.go`

Here is my case. I am learning Terraform to deploy AWS Lambda function.
I am following an [terraform official document](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/lambda-api-gateway) to deploy a hello function.
The page guides me to create a function using Node.js and I rewrite it using Go.

Here is my modified part of main.tf.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "hello_world" {
  function_name = "HelloWorld"
  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket.id
  s3_key    = aws_s3_object.lambda_hello_world.key
  runtime = "go1.x"
  handler = "hello"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_hello_world.output_base64sha256
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn
}
```

I deleted the `hello.js` file and created the `hello.go` file.

My `hello.go` is the same as [AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)
type MyEvent struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error) 
{
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", name.Name ), nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

After deploying the lambda function using terraform, we can verify it.

```
% aws lambda invoke --region=us-east-1 --function-name=HelloWorld response.json
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My issue (I think) was the zipping tool / GOOS=windows was set wrong.

[Zip Go file using AWS Lambda Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311824/zip-go-file-using-aws-lambda-tool)

My setup is windows + following a golang tutorial. Published to lambda, all appeared fine, got the error and was correctly named and built etc.

I think it's the zipping tool, using build-lambda-zip and now it works for me. Note: I tried using another command to get the tool
`go.exe get -u github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cmd/build-lambda-zip` however this didn't actually get the tool for me.

Hopefully this saves someone else half an hour of googling

Answer (score 1):

What the accepted answer says, use environmental variables.
But note the following: *Using Powershell (Jetbrains IDEs use it as well) requires different commands than cmd (see [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-package.html#golang-package-windows)).*
Namely, for cmd:

```
set GOOS=linux
set GOARCH=amd64
set CGO_ENABLED=0
```

for Powershell:

```
$env:GOOS = "linux"
$env:GOARCH = "amd64"
$env:CGO_ENABLED = "0"
```

Also the Go program needs to have `package main` as well as a `main()` method ([doc](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Program_execution)).
In the AWS runtime config the **handler name** needs to be named like the **build file**. It doesnt matter how the .zip or .go is named.

Comment: thank you -- i had my suspicions but the only thing I was missing is my package name also had to match the handler :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to my Go setting.

As I use Go Version Manager, I had to run the following to specify the right Go path before compiling my project.

```
gvm use go1.x.x
```

Proceed to compile then deploy.

Answer (score 0):

My case was a strange one, but I'll leave it here in case someone needs it.

I built my executable in a Docker container and then used `Docker cp` to put the file in a local directory. Then I zipped the executable and deployed it.

Apparently, `Docker cp` creates a symlink-like file rather than an actual file, so it just wouldn't work.

My solution was just to use `sudo cp` and copy the executable as another file, which created a physical file, and deployed that instead.

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with the program; it's a configuration issue.
Please try to give the complied go file name in the lambda console under Go Runtime settings -

In my case my go lambda compiled file is test so configured Handler as test and it worked for me.

[Example Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nos24.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution is very simple.

I was wrong with the command build.
what I did was `go build .` instead of `go build main.go`

the zip file should be `main.zip`.

and the handler info section in console AWS should be named `main`.
not `handler` because lambda calls the main function first

Comment: you did your best but this does not rely add anything that is not in the other answers

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If deploying with SAM cli, make sure to run "sam build" before the "sam deploy"

Answer (score 0):

In my case this had to do with the image I was using to build the go binaries.  I switched from using alpine to using amazon linux 2 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

setting environment variable CGO_ENABLED to 0 solved my problem, this is when using sam local start-api to locally test endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I use sam for locally debug use and hit this issue too, then I found I set the wrong path in my `template.yaml`, actually, after run `GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build -gcflags "all=-N -l" -o bin/bootstrap .`, there is a bin folder generated in my root path, then I need to add this path to CodeUri property in template.yaml file, such as(I use MacOs with M1 chip):

```
Resources:
  YourAppName:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./bin
      Handler: bootstrap
      Runtime: go1.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Environment:
        Variables:
          ENVIRONMENT_NAME: YOUR_ENV_NAME
      Events:
        ScheduleEvent:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: "rate(1 minute)"
```