# Zip Go file using AWS Lambda Tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I am trying to generate an exe file with this command in windows 10

go.exe get -u github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cmd/build-lambda-zip

the file comes back as linux_amd64/build-lambda-zip instead of build-lambda-zip.exe

Has anyone experienced this and know what the fix is?
I am using the AWS docs here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-package.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cross compile from Windows to Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829155/how-to-cross-compile-from-windows-to-linux)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create `bin`, use `install` command with override `$GOOS` var ([Compile and install packages and dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) ):

```
GOOS=windows go install  github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cmd/build-lambda-zip
```

`exe` file will be store to `$GOBIN`.

Answer (score 1):

there was another way to access the aws lambda tools

I found it in

%USERPROFILE%\dotnet\tools.store\amazon.lambda.tools\4.0.0\amazon.lambda.tools\4.0.0\tools\netcoreapp2.1\any\Resources\build-lambda-zip.exe

if its not there we can get it from aws directly but running this command

dotnet tool update -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools